# ExpressionEngine 1.6.8 Admin login loop

Tags: ee1, login, admin, loop

I have uploaded a site into a sub folder onto my server and when I try to login into the admin area, it allows me to login, however when I go to click on any link, it redirects/loops me, logging me out and taking me back to the admin login page.

Site was working fine locally and the previous SQL which is live (redesigning the site) also allows me to login fine without this redirect problem.

Could it be anything to do with the fact it is in a folder on the server E.G.

httpdocs/new/...

I also thought it might be the .htaccess file throwing it off, maybe with the www. redirect and removing the index.php, but when the problem keeps arising with and without a .htaccess file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a second site on this hosting account, the cookies are probably getting in the way. Add this to your new site's config file and set the prefix to something unique:

<strike>$config['cookie_prefix'] = "new";</strike>

**EDIT**
I just saw this was an EE1 site. Use this instead:

```
$conf['cookie_prefix'] = "new";
```

Comment: I put this into the config file and it ends up showing an error message saying Server Error and leaving me unable to access any of the site.

Comment: Just noticed this is an EE1 site... I edited the code to use in my answer. What I posted initially is for EE2.

Comment: I also realised this when after trying the original code and unfortunately it still did the same thing, throwing up the same Server Error.

Comment: Is it possible the quotes aren't copying correctly? Adding this code shouldn't cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config file to make sure all of your paths are linking to the sub-folder? Also, there could be a cookie path or name throwing it off?